# How to forward one POST request to two external urls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, ecmascript-6

One SaaS provider we use has a webook field, but only allows a single url to be entered. In fact, we need this webhook to be sent to two analytics services, so I need to figure out a way to write a custom endpoint that forwards the entire request to as many other endpoints as we need (currently 2).

What is the easiest way to do this with node and express? If I am not mistaken, a simple redirect would not work for multiple POSTs, right?

I am not sure what the headers or even request content will look like, but it needs to be preserved as much as possible in case auth is in headers etc.

This is what I have so far, but it's nowhere near complete:

```
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
console.log('Request received: ', req.originalUrl)
const forwardRequests = config.forwardTo.map(url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    superagent
      .post(url)
      .send(req)
      .end((endpointError, endpointResponse) => {
        if (endpointError) {
          console.error(`Received error from forwardTo endpoint (${url}): `, endpointError)
          reject(endpointError)
        } else {
          resolve(endpointResponse)
        }
      })
  })
})
Promise.all(forwardRequests)
  .then(() => res.sendStatus(200))
  .catch(() => res.sendStatus(500))
})
```

I get an error, because `superagent.send` is just for the content... how can I *duplicate a request entirely and send it off*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *duplicate a request entirely and send it off* to various endpoint, you can use the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) module with `req.pipe(request(<url>))` and `Promise.all`.

According to request module's document:

> You can also pipe() from http.ServerRequest instances, as well as to http.ServerResponse instances. The HTTP method, headers, and entity-body data will be sent.

Here is an example:

```
const { Writable } = require('stream');
const forwardToURLs = ['http://...','http://...'];
app.post('/test', function(req, res) {
  let forwardPromiseArray = [];
  for (let url of forwardToURLs) {
    let data = '';
    let stream = new Writable({
      write: function(chunk, encoding, next) {
        data += chunk;
        next();
      }
    });
    let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      stream.on('finish', function() {
        resolve(data);
      });
      stream.on('error', function(e) {
        reject(e);
      });
    });
    forwardPromiseArray.push(promise);
    req.pipe(request(url)).pipe(stream);
  }

  Promise.all(forwardPromiseArray).then(function(result) {
    // result from various endpoint, you can process it and return a user-friendly result.
    res.json(result);
  }).catch(function() {
    res.sendStatus(500);
  });
});
```

Please note the above code should be placed before `body-parser` (if you are using it). Otherwise, the request won't be piped.